# Different sub-tables for each instance of parent class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have class *A* which has a list of *B* classes (simplified):

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> BData  { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Value  { get; set; }
}
```

This creates two tables - *AData* and *BData* where *BData* contains data of **all** *A* instances.
Since the list of *B* classes is pretty large for each instances of *A*, I would like to separate the *B* table, so each instance of *A* has its own *B* table. Something like:

`A a1 = new A();` - this creates table *BData1* and all *B* instances go to *BData1* not to a common *BData* table. Similarly `A a2 = new A();` - its *B* instances go to *BData2*, and so on

How can I achieve this using C# EF? Is there an attribute what I can put to `public List<B> BData  { get; set; }` which will control this behavior?

Thanks, Csaba

Comment: How many `B`s you have per `A`?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good DB design to me!  There should be no technical issue having millions or billions of rows in Table B in any good DB (and even some bad ones!!).  If you want this, then I would instead look to serialise Class B and store it in a variable in JSON on Table A, or expand Table A to include the columns needed for Class B as well.

Comment: I expect to have ~ 100 `A` and maybe 1,000,000 `B`s / `A`.

Comment: Post details of the class design and the target database environment.

Comment: The idea is to have several mobile applications (class A) and have their usage logged - kind of analytics (class B). The server is on Ubuntu using MySQL. How large will be the BData table depends on the number of users and usage, but it can be quickly big. If this is something what the server can't handle then I have to reconsider how the analytics will be logged and/or implement some kind of database cleanup (discard old data etc.). Anyway I'm just curious if it is possible to control the sub-table create/bind in EF.